# CKFinderJava 2.4.1 integration with struts 2 + spring 3.2.2 can not upload file

Tags: java, spring, struts2, ckfinder

I have installed ckfinder2.4.1 with struts2 + spring 3.2.2.
Ckfinder manager interface was displayed normally, however when I've uploaded a file, no response occurs. No errors, but the upload folders are empty.

The log file is below:

```
2015-01-28 22:15:33,127 DEBUG - Found item upload
2015-01-28 22:15:33,127 DEBUG - Item is a file upload
2015-01-28 22:15:33,141 DEBUG - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@1d94351], property=struts]
2015-01-28 22:15:33,142  INFO - Removing file upload D:\setup\Eclipse\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32\_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\DictionaryPro\upload_5031dfd0_14b311c9984__8000_00000000.tmp
```

Can anyone fix it?

Comment: Could you post your code, which handles the upload?

Comment: Should be xhr response, check it.

Comment: I integrated the sample link: http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP/Integration and http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP/CKEditor_Integration

Comment: I integrated the sample link: http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/Java/Integration